# How to use try and left join in a tidyverse setting?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I would like to do something like this:

```
df1 %>% 
  try(left_join(df2, by = c("col_a" = "col_b")))
```

I suppose I have to use safely() for this, but not sure how exactly.

Comment: Please read the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag.  Code posted to SO should be complete and self contained.  In particular all library statements and inputs must be provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problem is that the code in the question is passing `df1` to `try`.  You want to pass it to `left_join`.

Below all use the inputs `df1` and `df2` defined in the Note at the end.

The following are several alternate ways to deal with this returning `df1` if the left join fails.

**1) try** We can use `try` like this:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  { tmp <- try(left_join(., df2, by = c(demand = "fake")), silent = TRUE)
    if (inherits(tmp, "try-error")) . else tmp }
```

**1a)** Using base |> the body of the function on the RHS of the first |> could be written as a pipeline:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 |> 
  (\(x) 
    left_join(x, df2, by = c(demand = "fake")) |>  
    try(silent = TRUE) |>
    (\(y) if (inherits(y, "try-error")) x else y)()
  )()
```

**2) tryCatch** Another possibility is `tryCatch`

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  { tryCatch(left_join(., by = c(demand = "fake")), error = \(x) .) }
```

**3) safely** Using purrr we can do this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df1 %>% 
  { safely(left_join, .)(., df2, by = c("demand" = "fake"))$result }
```

### Note

```
df1 <- df2 <- BOD # test data
```

Comment: Thank you. Let's say I use: df1 %>% { try(left_join(., df2, by = c("demand" = "fake_column"))) }, I still get an error because one of the join columns is not present in the data. I am using try() to avoid this error. In case an error occurs, I just want to get df1 back. What is try doing in this case?

Comment: Have moved my comments to answer.